# How can a batch exit with -1 with MSBuild in a TFS build flow when there are no negative exits inside the series of batches

Tags: windows, batch-file, tfs, msbuild, exit-code

I've got a batch that keeps failing through TFS with an exit of `-1`.

The batch that gets called has no negative exits. It calls instead of running directly some other batches and commandline tools that can return a negative exit code, but they're all `call`ed, not ran directly, and when I set a failure point, I `exit /b 1` or `exit 1`

> ....targets (350): The command "call
>   C:\Build\BuildTools\callSigning.bat" exited with code -1.

Remoting into the failing box and running the batch there generates no error!

What could be triggering this `exit -1` with MSBuild? Is there some weird behind-the-scenes caveat that I'm just not aware of?

Inside the .proj file, I've got a line like this:

`<Exec Command="call $(SrcRoot)\BuildTools\callSigning.bat" ContinueOnError="false"/>`

And that batch has no negative exit codes...

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0

IF EXIST "%~dp0signVerification.log" echo Cert renewed and successfully signed once for this TFS job already&&exit 0

IF NOT EXIST .\renew_certificate.bat echo missing renew_certificate.bat&&exit 1

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

FOR /L %%T IN (1,1,5) DO (
    call %~dp0renew_certificate.bat
    IF NOT "!passed!"=="true" IF "!errorlevel!"=="0" Set passed=true&&exit /b 0
    IF NOT "!passed!"=="true" echo Re-trying signing iteration %%T && call ping 127.0.0.1 -n 61 > nul
)

IF NOT "%passed%"=="true" echo Signing did not pass && exit /b 1
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Where does `passed` come from?

Comment: Third line of the for loop: `IF NOT "!passed!"=="true" IF "!errorlevel!"=="0" Set passed=true&&exit /b 0`

Comment: Ah, yes! But it does not make sense, as you are leaving the script immediately after setting the variable, so the negative condition `if NOT "!passed!"=="true"` is always met and therefore executed (unless `passed` is already set to `true` in advance)...

Comment: It's a 5-iteration loop that bypasses script calls as soon as `passed` is set to `true` via exit code of `renew_certificate.bat`. `FOR /L` loops have weird exiting behavior; basically you can't just use exit /b 0 and pop out of it for some weird reason.

Comment: `exit /B` or `goto` will leave the `for /L` loop, although the loop always finishes in the background (not executing any more commands); this is actually true for all `for` loops in `cmd`...

Comment: Hm. Interesting. Well, that still doesn't explain a negative exit code :x But good to know, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely a side effect of the fact that `Exec` places your `Command` text in a `.exec.cmd` file in a temporary directory and calls `cmd.exe /C [that temporary .exec.cmd]`. As a result, paths may not be what you think and bugs involving quotation marks may surface. When I use `Exec` I leave little to chance and pass explicit paths, e.g.:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SomeCommand>
    "$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)SomeFile.bat" "$(SomeToolsDir)" "$(SomeLogFilePath)"
  </SomeCommand>
</PropertyGroup>
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SomeToolsDir)" Command="$(SomeCommand)" />
```

And in `SomeFile.bat`:

```
SET SomeToolsDir=%~1
SET SomeLogFilePath=%~2
SOMEPROGRAM.EXE -logfilepath "%SomeLogFilePath%"
```

Comment: How sneaky! I will try this out as soon as I can.

Comment: Yep, that was the ticket! Pesky `Exec`...I made a new property in the shared PropertyGroup in my build file, set it to `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)`, and since the original batch took no arguments, I sent that new variable the argument instead of using `%~dp0`. I guess I could have just used `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)` as the arg in hindsight...